# JDesktopPane external Application?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jdesktoppane

What's the purpose of JDesktopPanes? Just to Display Frames in it? Or is there a way to Launch an external jar or exe inside this DesktopPane?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not intended to run another jar or exe inside of it, it is just a Component in which you can have internal frames of class `JInternalFrame`.